# AbstractMethodError en hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Tengo un proyecto en spring que tengo que migrar a spring 5 con esto tambien debo de migrar a hibenate 5 con lo cual he tenido problemas.

Cuando creo un query hibernate me sale le siguiente error, he leido un poco y dicen que el error AbstractMethodError se trata de incompatibilidad de librerias

estoy usando
hibernate-core - 5.4.3.Final
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3014)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1676)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1565)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:730)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:989)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:947)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2693)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2676)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2510)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2505)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.list(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:96)
```

Comment: Hola @SaulR7, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.